# nmap -oG X.X.X.0-255 doesn't work and all my ports closed ( expected list of open ports )

Tags: network, nmap, virtualization, network-scanners

I'm running kali Linux on VirtualBox. I ran `sudo ifconfig` to get my IP and subnet mask (`X.X.X.15` and `255.255.255.0` for `eth0`)

I tried the command `nmap -oG X.X.X.0-255 -vv` but  I got

```
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 0.07 seconds
```

When I remove the `-oG` option, I get a result of **scanning 265 host** and one is `up` which is

```
X.X.X.15 // my ip
```

But all ports are closed. I don't know why. Can you help me?

I'm following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/VFJLMOk6daQ).

Comment: This is really looking like a networking question and not a security question. Let's boil down your question: you ran nmap on your own scanning machine and all ports were closed. Well, are they closed? Are any ports open?

Comment: Your `-oG` command failed because you have a syntax error. Please look at the tutorial again.

Comment: Yes I found all ports closed and I don't know any other method than nmap to check for my ports status.
thanks @schroeder I found the syntax error and I read the edited version of the question and it was helpful, thanks.

Comment: 1. nmap works oddly when scanning itself. 2. There are Linux commands to look for local open ports.